# Issue related to scope of variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want my code give me "2" as a output but this shows me "1" as an output.
Please tell me what changes must I do in my code so that it give me a correct result.

```
var a = 1;

function x() {
  var a = 2;

  function b() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self.a);
  }

  b();
}

x();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Global variables are properties of the `window` object, so `self.a` gives you `1` because `self` is `window`. (Further reading: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)).

Local variables are not properties of any object. They can't be accessed as if they were properties of an object. Just log `a` and not `self.a`.

Comment: It's working great when we use only "a" . But can you explain me another way to print "2"?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal Don't use `this`?

Comment: @PulkitAggarwal — Why do you need "another way"? Just `a` is the *correct* way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code which prints "2" to the browser console. Here I changed the function x to an object. Inside this I added "a" as a property and "b" as a function. Then finally call the b() function as "x.b()".

```
var a = 1;

var x=
{
    a :2,

    b: function()
    {
        var self = this;
        console.log(self.a);
    }


}

x.b();
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this out:

```js
var a = 1;
function x() {
  a = 2;
  function b() {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self.a);
  }
  b();
}
x();
```

Comment: Thanks for suggetion, But i dont know why people down voting even code is having true logic.

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. The question seems to be about how to read the correct variable, not about how to use only one variable.